# Morphisms between chiral CFTs

Tags: terminology, conformal-field-theory

This is a question about terminology.

Given two vertex algebras $V_1$ and $V_2$ (= chiral CFTs), there are two kinds of maps $V_1\to V_2$ that one might want to consider.

1) Morphisms of VOAs that send the conformal vector of $V_1$ to the conformal vector of $V_2$. In other words, morphisms that send the copy of the Virasoro algebra in $V_1$ to the copy of the Virasoro algebra in $V_2$. Examples of those come from e.g. from conformal embeddings. This type of morphism forces the central charges of $V_1$ and $V_2$ to be equal.

2) Morphisms of VOAs that are not required to send the conformal vector of $V_1$ to the conformal vector of $V_2$.
An example of the above notion is the inclusion of the trivial one dimensional VOA into some other VOA.

**Question:** is there some standard terminology used in physics to refer to those two kinds of morphisms between chiral CFTs?